# How can I account for very small amounts of time?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, time, integer

This is a strange question, but given the following results...

```
DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks;
```

= 3155378975999999999

```
new DateTime(DateTime.MaxValue.Year,
             DateTime.MaxValue.Month, 
             DateTime.MaxValue.Day, 
             DateTime.MaxValue.Hour, 
             DateTime.MaxValue.Minute, 
             DateTime.MaxValue.Second, 
             DateTime.MaxValue.Millisecond)
       .Ticks;
```

= 3155378975999990000

(And yes, I am aware that this can be done, however...)

```
new DateTime(DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks);
```

What do these 9999 ticks represent? How would I account for just the missing 9999 ticks manually? For example, let's say they represent Nanoseconds. Could I create an "AddNanoseconds" method?

Thanks!

Comment: There's already an `AddTicks` method.  Also the docs clearly say that each tick is 100ns (so 10 ticks = 1 microsecond)

Comment: I hope you're not trying to *measure* time to this precision with `DateTime.Now` or `DateTime.UtcNow`.  The precision of the computer's realtime clock is nowhere near as precise as the `DateTime` object can actually store.   If you're measuring things, use a `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks` is in ticks, while your maximized date "stops" at Millisecond, so the last 9999 ticks are not included.

Simple example to make this quite clear:

```
var maxTicks = DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks; 
Console.WriteLine("Max ticks:");
Console.WriteLine(maxTicks); // 3155378975999999999

var maxedDate = new DateTime(DateTime.MaxValue.Year,
                            DateTime.MaxValue.Month, 
                            DateTime.MaxValue.Day, 
                            DateTime.MaxValue.Hour, 
                            DateTime.MaxValue.Minute, 
                            DateTime.MaxValue.Second, 
                            DateTime.MaxValue.Millisecond);

var ticksFromDate = maxedDate.Ticks; 
Console.WriteLine("Max ticks from date:");
Console.WriteLine(ticksFromDate); // 3155378975999990000

var withExtraTicks = maxedDate.AddTicks(9999);
Console.WriteLine("Max date with ticks added:");
Console.WriteLine(withExtraTicks.Ticks); // 3155378975999999999

try{ 
    var tooLong = withExtraTicks.AddTicks(1); 
    Console.WriteLine("Note: This line will only be shown if run on Diskworld.");
}
catch(Exception ex){
    Console.WriteLine("Failed! Message:");
    // Will show the message:
    // "The added or subtracted value results in an un-representable DateTime."
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); 
}
```